# SQL запрос для записей на последнюю дату

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с названием diseases:

[image: Таблица]

Нужно сделать запрос с выводом RegNum, Type, Treatment, DateReg где для каждого значения Counter выводится только запись с последней датой, т.е.

```
RegNum  Treatment   Type    DateReg
WR634   Car         3       2019-04-08  
WR634   GunNe       4       2019-04-09  
WR634   Pilot       5       2019-04-08  
WR634   Hunter      6       2019-04-08  
WR634   POlice      7       2019-04-08
```

Порядок по типу не важен

Comment: *где для каждого значения Counter* Что-то я как-то не увидел поля `Counter` в результате... и вообще не увидел, чтобы оно хоть как-то учитывалось.

Comment: А можно посмотреть на плоды ваших трудов по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для каждого `Counter` получаете последнюю дату и выводите только эту строку:

```
select d.*
from (select d.counter, max(DateReg) as max_date_reg
      from diseases d
      group by d.counter
     ) m
    join diseases d on d.counter = m.counter and d.DateReg = m.max_date_reg
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через [max](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) вывести, к примеру:

```
SELECT RegNum, Type, Treatment, MAX(DateReg) as DateReg FROM `diseases` GROUP BY Treatment;
```

Comment: Пробовал похожий вариант раньше(GROUP BY Counter), а этот выводит все записи

Comment: Не может он никак выводить все записи при группировке.